# Production live streaming with Red5 - oflaDemo required?

Tags: flash, streaming, red5

I've just finished putting together a basic flash video chat client that publishes the camera to a stream and receives a similar stream from another client. (Something in the spirit of this [blog post](http://sunil-gupta.blogspot.com/2008/06/two-way-av-chat-application-with-fms3.html).)

The streams are being pub/sub'd to the "oflaDemo" that ships with Red5.

This seems to work fine for my prototype, but I'm concerned about having to use something with "demo" in the name if I were to roll this chat application into production. It seems that the alternative is to essentially re-write that demo, perhaps with a few more features, which doesn't seem right in order to take advantage of one of Red5's core functionalities.

So, my question is: what is standard/best practice for production live streams in Red5? Is the oflaDemo used? Do custom stream brokers have to be written? If I don't host it myself, do most hosts have their own (production-quality) version of oflaDemo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That demo was written for a conference quite some time ago and you are certainly welcome to use it. Many people use both the server and client side code to base their own code upon and this is also just fine and within the LGPL license. If you want to simply rename and deploy the application under another name, simply do a global search and replace for oflaDemo and repackage the classes. If you need further detail, just post a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I guess the real gist of my question is whether Red5 can do this functionality (or anything, really) "out of the box" or whether you have to code an application on top of the basic Red5 server?

Comment: Red5 "out-of-the-box" for 1.0 or current trunk includes two applications "live" and "vod". These allow live streaming and on-demand viewing without the need to install anything. Implementers that want to serve media files simple need to drop them in the correct location (usually the streams folder under the app in question by default). To broadcast live someone need only load the provided publisher / viewer demo or any of the "simple" swf applications.

Comment: I see, those will be helpful. But current production release is still v0.9.1 so for the stable release you'd have to use something like oflademo?

Comment: Any of the apps noted here would be ok for production, so long as you understand that they don't have any built-in security. The demos and samples are "wide-open". I answered a security related red5 question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702729/red5-security-tutorial

Comment: is there a simple demo which sends stream from xuggle to red5 and is played from red 5 server?. I have sent a stream to red5 using the wiki http://red5wiki.com/wiki/Live_streaming .But i am unable to subscribe to it . I am using as3 flash and also flvplayback 2.5 component in flash.

Comment: The flvplayback component has been known to have issues with some versions of red5. Most users have their own playback components or they use other players like JW. There are examples in the repo of how to construct your own playback